# Fancybox :TypeError: $(...).Fancybox is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-framework

I want to open a fancy box, But it give a Type error, can you please help me to solve this problem

view page contain following code

```
<script type="text/java script">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
</script>
```

HTML code

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#inline1" title="Add New Vessel">
    <div class="right-head-buton" style="color:#fff">Add New Vessel</div>
    </a>
```

I want to open inline id div in fancy box

```
<div id="inline1" style="width:800px;display: none;">
    <div class="lightbox">
    <?php echo $this->action('add', 'agency', NULL); ?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

In Bootstrap I include two files

```
$view->headScript()->appendFile($view->baseUrl('/public/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js'));
$view->headScript()->appendFile($view->baseUrl('/public/js/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5'));
```

Comment: Are you loading two JavaScript versions by any chance? Or is the `jquery.fancybox.js` not loaded successfully?

Comment: I am using two more JavaScript <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script> for using date picker on same page

Comment: Well, then that's the problem. The `$` you use in `$('.fancybox').fancybox();` is not the jQuery version you added the plugin to. Is there a specific reason you are including multiple jQuery versions?

Comment: For fancybox i use these files: jquery-1.10.1.min.js, jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5. is there any problem for using datepicker and fancybox on same page

Answer (score 7):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $= jQuery.noConflict();
```

noconflict in your jQuery in a single page 
may be this answer will help you.
and one more thing use highest version of a javascript file like only use 
jquery 1.3.min.js between jquery 1.3.min.js and jquery 1.3.5.min.js

Comment: Oh man, can't even tell you how long I've been fighting this. Thank you! Just a minor correction on the capitalization of jQuery, otherwise it breaks: var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

Answer (score 1):

The "no conflict" trick helps. To use an author's existing plugin code, you can wrap it in an IIFE:

```
// IIFE passing in jQuery.noConflict()
(function(jQuery){

     // Original author's plugin code
     // ...
     jQuery("a.fancybox").fancybox({ ... }
     // ...

})(jQuery.noConflict());
```

I've had to do this for two WordPress plugins to get them working with Firefox: *Easy FancyBox* and *FancyBox for Wordpress*. I hope this helps.

Comment: I ran into this problem using BootStrap. Once I moved the FancyBox script below BootStrap script, error went away.